# Creating a 2D Sprite Based Game in C++ without OpenGL, Vulkan, etc

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d

This might not be the best place to pose this question. Just a warning. Anyways, continue. I was wondering if there is a way to make a simple 2D game purely using the command prompt without any graphics libraries like OpenGL and Vulkan, as I have already made a fairly adequate real-time game engine with OpenGL and Vulkan. Just for a little bit of extra information, I am on Windows and have a fairly large understanding of most advanced C++ topics. Are there any API functions where I can draw pixels directly to the console? I have seen that used before but didn't fully understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "2D sprite-based", I'm guessing you want to have actual raster graphics and not ascii graphics (i.e. [text-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_game))

If you're going to do this, you need to have a way to interface with the integrated graphics hardware or card.

On Windows, there is the GDI.

I would get started with this link. [Microsoft GDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/windows-gdi)

Comment: I know this is not how comments are supposed to be used, but really, thanks so much! :3